# Sub report content not showing in the main report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

In Jasper report i created main report and sub report, when i preview the sub report it's showing the data, when i preview the main report that sub report data is not showing on the main report, instead of the content its showing a straight line. i passed parameter from main report to sub report using parameter map. but, i couldn't find the reason for this problem. Then i created another 2 sub report with some other queries and attached those report into the main report. In that one report can shows all the data, but another one not showing the data.
I checked all the both properties, both are same only.

I was very frustrated with my design, can any one point out my mistake and guide me in the right way.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Please post your main report setting to send parameters, and also your sub report query, and parameter list

Comment: can you just provide us the report design and sub_report properties?

Comment: I added my sub report properties